# Can I leave and re enter in Italy with a student visa and without the permesso?

Tags: student-visa, italy

My permesso appointment (first) is on February, and I want to go home (Brazil) the end on December. Although I do not have the permesso my student visa still valid and it has multiple entries. The flight has scale in Portugal on both ways, going out and returning to Europe.

Is it OK to return with the permesso receipt and the student visa?

Comment: This is not a question about moving long term, it’s a question about travelling. Although OP is themselves an expat it doesn’t make the question off topic.

Comment: ‘Has scale’ – do you mean a layover?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the receipt of permesso and the visa then yes, because the former is proof that your permesso is on process and the very receipt was issued by them in the first place, but nevertheless your multiple entry visa is enough if not expired, so you may be sure in both ways.

Answer (score 0):

You can return to Italy via Portugal without your permesso di soggiorno as long as your student visa is still valid and not expired. The receipt is not necessary and not used in this case.